# LayoutInflater is causing an exception

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am attempting to use the layout tricks #3 described in Android Layout Tricks #3: Optimize, Part 1 and I am getting an error when its trying to find the png file that I am using as the button obj my XML file for the button bar is the following .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <include
        layout = "@drawable/button_yes"
        android:id="@+id/okLabel" />
    <include
        layout="@drawable/button_no"
        android:id="@+id/cancelLabel" />
</merge>
```

and this is called by the java script......

```
package com.bobocode.culliganapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;


public class OkCancelBar extends FrameLayout {
    public OkCancelBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.okcancelbar, this, true);

    }
}
```

which is being instantiated by ..............

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:okCancelBar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bobocode.culliganapp">

<FrameLayout android:background="@drawable/culliganapp1"
    android:id="@+id/secondpage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center"
        android:padding="12dip"
        />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center"
            android:padding="12dip"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Does your water have an unpleasant taste or odor?"
            android:id="@+id/question"
             />
</FrameLayout>  
     <com.bobocode.culliganapp.OkCancelBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:background="#AA000000"
        okCancelBar:okLabel="Yes"
        okCancelBar:cancelLabel="No" 

        />
</merge>
```

any help would surely be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify a drawable for your background you'll need to include the png in your drawable directory and specify it on your OkCancelBar with `android:background="drawable/somepng"`.

Comment: Thanks Robby sometimes it just takes another look I needed to actually create the buttons in layout as an include and it worked My bad

Answer (score 0):

Use normal character like "yesbutton" . And i don't know why you want to do :

```
 Layout ="@drawable/button_yes"
 just do something like android:background="@drawable/yesbutton"
 i don't know what 
 layout is, is not even android because all attributs starts with "android:".
```